# Unable to use Style settings

Tags: pine-script

I am unable to find out why the indicator I made using pinescript won't let me change colors etc. in the style settings.

[TradingView Style settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XVJy.png)

I used code similar to this multiple times, but i have used it in other indicators too and never had a problem like this.

```
color = bullish ? color.green : color.red
```

Comment: I'm having the same happen on my custom indicator. Can't tell what it is as well, which makes me think it's some obscure bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without full code. The

The problem you described might be if you somehow cast your `color` variable  to `na` in your code, e.g

```
color plot_color = (na)
//instead of
color plot_color = color(na)
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything where I did that in the code, for now I will just use color inputs until I find a better solution.